# How to generate .jar library via existing project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, export

I'm not **java** developer,so it not clear for me,how can i achieve my goal(an library .jar ).

I've made an Android application project(via Android studio),where i successfully added native library
[image: NativeLibb]

Also a have implemented MainActivity(where was added some controls/calling camera API and etc) and ***class***,that i need to use in another project.

So this ***class*** using methods and others stuff from a ***native libb***.
[image: Structure of project]

The problem is how to **pack all necessary stuff** to an ***.jar*** library.

I've tried to do something like this(via **build.gradle**):

```
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete){
    delete 'release/MyCustomLib.jar'
}
task exportJar(type: Copy){
    from('src/main')
    into('release/') include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'MyCustomLib.jar')
}
exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Solved by my self. ill show how to do this,little bit later.